# liquibase exception DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.rollback is not allowed during a global transaction

Tags: java, spring, websphere, liquibase

I have a spring application deplyoed in WebSphere container.

I trying to initialize data using liquibase.

This is my DataSource configuration:

```
@Bean
public JndiTemplate jndi() {
    return new JndiTemplate();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new WebSphereUowTransactionManager();
}

@Bean(name = "primary")
public AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName(PERSTESTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    return jndi().lookup(DATA_SOURCE_ADDRESS, DataSource.class);
}
```

And this is the code that runs database initialisation:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class Startup {

    @Autowired
    private DbInit dbInit;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            dbInit.doMigrations(null);
        } catch (SQLException | LiquibaseException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    }
```

I get an exception on application startup:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.rollback is not allowed during a global transaction.
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.rollback(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1143)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:197)
    ... 142 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.rollback is not allowed during a global transaction.
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:340)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.rollback(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1141)
    ... 143 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.rollback is not allowed during a global transactionи.
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.rollback(WSJdbcConnection.java:3372)
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:337)
    ... 144 more
```

I know that I can't use `rollback()` in container-managed transaction but I don't know, how to configure this for liquibase.

I've tried to set `Non-transactional data source` property in WS DataSource configuration but it didn't help.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: setting `transactional=false` is the first thing I would have guessed too... Since that didn't work, do you have `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` set in your persistence.xml?

Comment: @Andy Guibert Method `doMigrations` is not transactional